# Coming from ColdFusion, where and how to set Session Variables in PHP

Tags: php, path, session-variables, session-state

I've left ColdFusion and trying to get up to speed with PHP. First off, in building an app I'm trying to set an Application variable for the include paths, in CF I would use Application.FilePath = "/myWebApp/" and use to set up all includes template files. In PHP I'm not finding something similar.

I'm also struggling with setting Session specific variables. In CF, I would also set them in the Application.cfc/Application.cfm file as session.mySessionVarName. In PHP I'm not seeing a similar place to put these so they're available throughout the webapp, and the current session.

I thought this may be a common question but I didn't find anything related.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a session, [sesson_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();
```

add a value to a session:

> ```
> $_SESSION['name'] = 'value';
> ```

End a session, [session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

```
session_destroy();
```

Save path for sessions, [session_save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php):

Comment: Thank you. Is there a file that loads before all others? Again, in CF the Application.cfc is called before all other files, so I could set my Application and Session variables. Because this file only loads once on each request, I wouldn't have to worry about the session_start() running twice anywhere.

Comment: You should worry about your code structure if you are worried about calling session_start twice. It is not loaded before anything else. It's loaded when you start a session. If a session cookie is present it loads the file associated to it.

Comment: @SteveHarvey: Thats completely determined by how you structure your code. If you design it to use a single entry point then yes, if not then you have tons entry points and you need to ensure the session is started on both of those. You may find working with a framework easier since this is generally dictated for you.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks guys. There are quite a few differences in PHP that I'll have to learn. I'll take a look at the frameworks as well.